# Angular9 http post CORS issue

Tags: php, angular9

I am new to Angular9, I have tried to save data by calling a php API from my angular9 application, but geting the following error.
I have test this service from postman, which is working fine and save data successfully

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1/angularCRUDservices/user/saveEmployee' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

**Please Note:** get method is working fine to fetch data,
```

my Angular service:

```
 reqHeader = new HttpHeaders(
        { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'No-Auth':'True',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Header':'Access-Control-Allow-Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,POST,DELETE,PATCH,PUT,OPTIONS'
         }
         );

    constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){}
    saveEmployee(formData:Employee){
        console.log(formData);
      this.httpClient.post<{response:any,success:boolean}>("http://127.0.0.1/angularCRUDservices/user/saveEmployee",formData,{
        headers : this.reqHeader
      })
      .subscribe((response)=>{
          console.log(response);
      })
    }
```

php service code:

setting headers in constructor:

```
    public function __construct()
     {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->model('user_model','usr');

            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access');
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,DELETE,PATCH,PUT,OPTIONS");
            header('Content-Type: application/json, charset=utf-8');

     }
```

service:

```
 public function saveEmployee()
     {

        $input = array();
        try
        {
            $UserID = $this->input->post('id');
            $input['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
            $input['gender'] = $this->input->post('gender');
            $input['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
            $input['mobile'] = $this->input->post('mobile');
            $input['department'] = 'test';//$this->input->post('department');
            $input['isActive'] = 1;//$this->input->post('isActive');
            $input['photo'] = 'testphoto';//$this->input->post('photo');

            $output["response"] = $this->usr->saveUser($input,$UserID); // call model query to save data into DB
            $output["success"] = true;
        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            $output["success"] = false;
            $output["error"] = $ex->getMessage();
        }
        echo json_encode((object)$output);
        exit;

     }
```

Comment: Why are you putting a `access-control-allow-origin` on the **request** in the first place?!

Answer (score 0):

if this is for development and not production,you can use a proxy to get arround the issue. add a json file to your root project named 'proxy.configuration.json'

remember to change the target to your api in the example below

```
{
    "/api/*": {
     "target": "https://localhost:44362",
     "secure": false,
     "logLevel": "debug",
     "changeOrigin": true
     }
}
```

then run ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json

Answer (score 0):

you have to add Authorization header key in Access-Control-Allow-Headers(in the backend)

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization (when you give like this it accepts specified headers only.means if you want to accept another key like authorization you have to mention that key name)

or

you can give like this also

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *